# Maven Dependency missing artifact : jhotdraw

Tags: java, maven

I am currently working on a Java project using Maven. In my pom.xml I am getting this error.

> Missing artifact org.jhotdraw:jhotdraw:jar:6.0b1

I have added this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jhotdraw</groupId>
    <artifactId>jhotdraw</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to my pom.xml. But still the error is same.

Can someone help me?

Comment: can you provide the command you are running (ie. mvn <mvn goal> ) and the error log trace.

Comment: First - does it build from the command line? If not, identify the exact error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That version of org.jhotdraw.jhotdraw does not exist on Maven Repository, the last version available on Maven Repository is [7.4.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jhotdraw/jhotdraw/7.4.1)

Either you have made an error as to the version or group id (I see there is a 7.6.0 package under `org.opentcs.thirdparty.jhotdraw`, but don't know if it's the same). Alternatively, you may have to manually download and install that package, check out... 
[How to include custom library into maven local repository](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/)